SQL Server 2022 returns NULL for COLUMNPROPERTY function call
A client installation fails to return a zero or one value for a COLUMNPROPERTY function when querying for information about a table definition.
The query in question is searching for any column(s) with IDENTITY properties set:
select COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
where TABLE_SCHEMA = '[schema]' 
  and TABLE_NAME = '[tablename]' 
  and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1

This returns no rows, even though there is an identity column defined for the table.
While researching, we asked if they would execute this query:
select 
    *, 
    COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') AS "Identity" 
from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = '[schema]' 
    and TABLE_NAME = '[tablename]'

It returns a row for each column in the table with the expected metadata, but the "Identity" call returns NULL.
The only other question on this site which addresses the same issue is from many years ago and has no answers.
Locally, when I am testing with a test user account, I can only get either the expected 0 or 1 result, or no rows at all.
If I revoke the view definition permission on the database (or system) with
deny VIEW DEFINITION to testuser

the query returns no rows at all.
If I revoke either PERFORMANCE or SECURITY view from the user, I get all rows with 0/1 values.
deny VIEW PERFORMANCE DEFINITION to testuser

I have not found any useful information on Microsoft sites: some say "returns NULL if incorrect request" and others say "May return NULL if insufficient permissions."

Why not just check the value of is_identity in sys.columns? If you want information of columns specific for SQL Server, why use INFORMATION_SCHEMA?

Have them try and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 0 --- I suspect they will still get NULL.  Also try the query without any table or schema in the WHERE clause.  This will isolate if the user does not have proper permissions for the system function, or for the specific table you are trying to query.

Also, verify your client is running against the correct database, either in the drop down in the upper left of management studio, or via a USE database_name at the start of the query

What does object_id(TABLE_NAME) return? It is by no means clear whether that returns NULL or not you should investigate that first. It can return NULL due to permissions or due to only using a one part name and taking no account of schema

So far no luck on Kevin's suggestions or Martin Smiths.
The query returns the following columns, all with values:
TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
and more items.
This means 1) the database is right, 2) the schema is right, 3) the user has rights to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA for this database.
To Thom A's suggestion, we may be able to use sys.columns for this client & this database version, but this is an application query so if we change that then EVERY client would use the same, which could break things for other servers & versions that currently work.

It was our understanding some year ago, when we wrote this, that INFORMATION_SCHEMA was the recommended way to get certain information about columns in a version-independent way. It has worked for dozens of other installations and hundreds of different SQL servers - just not this one.

The reply by @MartinSmith was on the right track. The schema (and optionally database) should have been passed to the object_id function.
object_id(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME)
grabs the correct results.
The original, which only uses the TABLE_NAME string, always returns the table in the user's default schema - which in this case did not include a table by that name, while the schema being processed did.
To get info on a table in another database, the catalog can be added as well:
object_id(TABLE_CATALOG+'.'+TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME)
